# How to limit amount of files sent to HTTP 2 / Server Push + Nginx

Tags: nginx, http2, server-push

I'm configuring my server to work with HTTP 2 Server Push.

I could make it work, but or the browser or the nginx  is limiting the amount of files to "push" in 10. I have a much bigger list of items (they are below).

Anyone knows if there is something in nginx that I need to config?

Chrome print below... Lok at the Initiator, only 10 items has the "push"
[Chrome network image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKZlH.png)

My environment is:

```
3 Dockers containers. 
1 php 7.3 container;
1 nginx 14.0.0 container;
1 mysql 8 container;
```

My nginx site config (ommited ssl certificate)

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;


    client_max_body_size 4M;

    include /etc/nginx/snippets/general-security-headers.conf;

    location / {                
        try_files $uri \$uri /index.php?$args;
        http2_push_preload on;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass phpserver;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        http2_push_preload on;
    }

}
```

===== SOLVED ======

Edit: I found the config, it is the "http2_max_concurrent_pushes". 
I added `http2_max_concurrent_pushes 100;`
in my nginx site config inside the "server" scope

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: thank you @BarryPollard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer =D.

I found the config that i needed to change. It is the "http2_max_concurrent_pushes".
I added `http2_max_concurrent_pushes 100;` in my nginx site config inside the "server" scope